# React-dates how to recognize in which way user choose data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

How to recognize if User chose data by either pressing "Enter" button or by mouse click?

Below is my code:

```
<SingleDatePicker
    date={this.state.date}
    isOutsideRange={() => false}
    isDayHighlighted={day => isSameDay(moment(new Date()),moment(day))}
    daySize={30}
    verticalSpacing={2}
    onDateChange={date => {
        this.setState({ date });
        if(date) {
            this.props.onSaveValue(date.unix());
        }
    }}
    displayFormat={this.props.dateFormat}
    focused={this.state.focused}
    numberOfMonths={1}
    placeholder={this.props.dateFormat}
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) =>{
        this.setState({ focused });
        this.props.isCalendarOpen(focused)
    }}
/>
```

I have simple `SingleDatePicker` and I didn't find some way to recognize how User chose data, without `addeventlisener` and other listeners.

Comment: you will much better and quick responses if you have boilerplate code with you.

Comment: i added code, but don't understand how it help you

Answer (score 1):

As per [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html.) Documentation for ReactJS,

1. To identify if `Enter` is hit you can use `onChange` method call on input.
2. To identify mouse event, you can use `onClick` to identify the click event. So the code shall look as below;

   ```
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleEvent = this.handleCommonEvent.bind(this);
   }

   handleCommonEvent: function(e) {
       if(e.nativeEvent 
          && e.nativeEvent.type 
          && e.nativeEvent.type == 'click'){
            // do something here on mouse click
       } else if(e.nativeEvent 
          && e.nativeEvent.type 
          && e.nativeEvent.type == 'input'){
          // do something here on keyboard input
       }

   }
   ```

In your input field add below stuff as well.

```
<...onClick={ this.handleEvent } onChange={ this.handleEvent }..../>
```

> **NOTE**: `e` is a synthetic event. React defines these synthetic events according to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/), so you don’t need to worry about cross-browser compatibility.